# RouterLink in Angular 2 RC.6 not redirecting

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My issue is I want my navigation bar to be on every page. In my app.component.ts I have the following:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
         <nav-bar></nav-bar>
         <home></home>
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

First here is my routes.config.ts file:

```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {path:'home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path:'login', component: LoginComponent}

];

export const appRoutingProviders: any = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Now at it will render the way I want it to. However once I click on Login I want it to redirect me to a different page, but it leaves me on the `<home></home>` page and scatters my login forms input, labels and button around in random places.

I want to click on Login and go to a whole new page.

login.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl:'./login.html'
})
```

If you look at my GIT link my HTML files are in `frontend->build` then it should be easy to figure it out from there.

Git Link  [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/drewjocham/AngularIssue)

Comment: Where is Navigation.html used in your project? I can't find it on the github project

Comment: Do you want the navbar to disappear when you click a link?

Comment: @FedericoP build directory.

Comment: @FedericoP I want the Nav-bar to remain on all pages. But I want it to render a new page.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your browser console when you click on login?

Comment: What do you want ?

Comment: @micronyks I want to simply click on any link in the nav bar it takes me to that page. NOT keep me on the same page and display my component (in this example my login form).

Comment: What  you want to say again I'm unable to understand.

Comment: @micronyks I want to simply click on any link (Login, Register, Contact) in the navigation bar, it than takes me to a different page while keeping the Navigation bar present on the next page. Currently it keeps me on the same page and displays my component, in this example my login form in my Navigation bar and doesn't redirect me.

Comment: `Currently it keeps me on the same page and displays my component` so what's wrong. if you click on register, your navbar will remain same but you'll have registerview in router-outlet. I guess same thing is happening so what's wrong?

Comment: Not the behavior I want. `NOT keep me on the same page and display my component (in this example my login form).` I want to go to a `WHOLE NEW PAGE` which will display say just my login form.

Comment: @micronyks do you understand what I mean now?

Comment: so you don't need navbar in login page?

Comment: @micronyks yes every single page will have a navbar. However once you click anything in the navbar everything below the navbar will be different, in other words `a whole new page with the nav bar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124338/discussion-between-drew1208-and-micronyks).

Comment: @micronyks please see my updated question.

Comment: Ok understood your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you click `Login link`, it still shows `Home view`.Right?

You just to need to change you AppComponent View to this,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
         <nav-bar></nav-bar>
         <home></home>                          //<<<===removed home selector from this line.
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

You also need to change routes to shown below,

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {path:'', redirecTo:'home',  pathMatch: 'full'}  //<<<===added this
    {path:'home', component: HomeComponent },
    {path:'login', component: LoginComponent}

];
```

Comment: Very nice thank you. But weird on my `<h2>Form</h2>` displays and not my form.

Comment: Sorry.... I does redirect now but doesn't display my form, just the `<h2></h2>` tags. I am sure the issue is somewhere else. Thank you for your help on this issue. I marked it as solved.

Comment: Thanks ! Glad it helped you.